# Dynamic UITextView height in UITableView using auto layout?

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, height, uitextview, row-height

I made a customCell and on that cell i have three UITextview and I want the textView to dynamically size itself when the remote text is filling up the all three UITextView, and I want the cell to dynamically size itself according to the textView.
i saw many answers related to this but couldn't find any helpful solution for me,
i'm using auto layout and made all the constrains and try every answer that i found in here but not solved yet,
Would anyone please tell me any tutorial that i can follow or an easy step by step things for understanding how can i achieve the desired result,
your help really appreciated

Please don't be too harsh cause I'm a beginner.
Thanks

Comment: Use auto layout as explained [here](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/09/uitable-view-cell-dynamic-height-ios7.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like [Deepak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243644/deepak-kumar) said, you should set `estimatedRowHeight` to a value greater than zero and `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Also, your vertical constraints should cover the whole cell.

For a more detailed explanation you can take a peak at a [post](http://candycode.io/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableview-using-auto-layout-like-reminders-app/) I wrote which describes how to achieve a self-sizing text view with a working sample project.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following things then it will work, 
 - Use estimatedRowHeight on table view 
 - Have proper constraints from top of the cell to the bottom so that auto layout engine can calculate the height properly
 - Content compression resistance priority on text views should be 1000